# how to get the list of redis cache keys in sorted order by creation time

Tags: redis

I have the n number of keys in my redis server with some data. Now i want to check what all keys got created in last two months. How to check this. Is there any way to sort all cache keys in redis-cli by creation time or anything?

Answer (score 3):

Redis doesn't store this information. You need to do this explicitly. There are many ways you can achieve this. Some of them are:

1. SET time or date or datetime string when setting key
   ex:
   `SET key1 data`
   `SET key1:date "12-JULY-2018"`
2. Make data Object type - Add an explicit key of created at and then store it to Redis. Then sort it in your own application.
3. Create Sets/Lists of each hour/day/month and keep pushing all the keys to those lists. You can then retrieve keys for each hour/day/month. Now get data using these keys.
   ex:
   `SET key1 data` // At this point date is "12-JULY-2018"
   `SADD "JULY-SET" key1`
   Now you can get all keys of JULY by doing this:
   `SMEMBERS "JULY-SET"`

Comment: but m woried about already pushed data in redis, and not about future data, which we'll store with your idea.

Comment: the data is with TTL or without?